# Node JS Concurrency Handling Coding Interview Question

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, callback, single-threaded

I attended a NodeJS coding interview. Got below code which executes asynchronously from different browsers(to be assumed). Our solution needs to lock the execution of function if the update by ID is same but called from different place (say browser). And then release the lock for next request's execution.

Here no changes to be made for the mentioned code below.

```js
async function update(id, data) {
    console.log(`start --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
    await randomDelay(); //update is happening here
    console.log(`end --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
}

//=============================================================================
//================= Don't change anything below ===============================
//=============================================================================

//---- update() is getting called from many places ----
update(1, "browser 1");
update(1, "browser 2");

//========================= Utility functions ===================================
//========================= Don't change any here================================

async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
    });
}

async function randomDelay() {
    const randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    return sleep(randomTime);
}
```

This will give an output like below.

```
start --> id:1, data:browser 1
start --> id:1, data:browser 2
end --> id:1, data:browser 1
end --> id:1, data:browser 2
```

The expected answer is

```
start --> id:1, data:browser 1
end --> id:1, data:browser 1
start --> id:1, data:browser 2
end --> id:1, data:browser 2
```

Please note the comments in code "Don't change anything below". What would be the possible solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table of [queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) keyed by ID so only jobs with the same ID run consecutively, otherwise they run concurrently.

```js
let hash = {};
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.isBusy = false;
    this.jobs = [];
  }

  push(jobFn) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.jobs.push({
        jobFn,
        resolve
      });
      this.next();
    });
  }

  next() {
    if (this.isBusy || this.jobs.length === 0) return;
    this.isBusy = true;
    let currJob = this.jobs.shift();
    return currJob.jobFn().then((data) => {
      currJob.resolve(data);
      this.isBusy = false;
      this.next();
    });
  }
}

async function update(id, data) {
  const updateFn = async () => {
    console.log(`start --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
    await randomDelay(); //update is happening here
    console.log(`end --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
  };
  if (id in hash) {
    hash[id].push(updateFn);
  } else {
    hash[id] = new Queue(updateFn);
    hash[id].push(updateFn);
  }
}

//=============================================================================
//================= Don't change anything below ===============================
//=============================================================================

//---- update() is getting called from many places ----
update(1, "browser 1");
update(1, "browser 2");
update(2, "browser 1");
update(2, "browser 2");
update(1, "browser 3");
update(1, "browser 4");

//========================= Utility functions ===================================
//========================= Don't change any here================================

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  });
}

async function randomDelay() {
  const randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  return sleep(randomTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for just `two` consecuence calls with different data as you expected, so I am working on extending it but for now, I hope will give you a good vision of how it should be implemented

```
const callStack = []
async function update(id, data) {
    const stackLen = callStack.length;
    let currentIndex;

    if (stackLen) {
        let currentCall = callStack[stackLen - 1];
        if (currentCall.start == true && currentCall.await == true) {
            setImmediate(() => update(id, data))
            return;
        }
        currentIndex = stackLen - 1;
        if (currentCall.args[0] == id && currentCall.args[1] !== data) {
            
            if (currentCall.await === true) {
                currentCall.start = true;
                update(id, data)
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        callStack.push({ args: [...arguments], await: true })
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    console.log(`start --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
    await randomDelay(); //update is happening here
    console.log(`end --> id:${id}, data:${data}`);
    callStack[currentIndex].await = false;
}
```